# Literature value of forward-backward asymmetry on the Z resonance?

Tags: specific-reference, standard-model, scattering-cross-section

I did a Standard Model calculation and I want to compare my answer to a measured value.

Does anyone know the literature value for the forward-backward asymmetry $\frac{\sigma_F - \sigma_B}{\sigma_F + \sigma_B}$

for the process $e^+e^- \to \mu^+\mu^-$ on the $Z$ resonance (where $\sigma_F = \int_0^1 d\cos \theta \frac{d\sigma}{d \cos \theta}, \sigma_B = \int_{-1}^0 d \cos\theta \frac{d\sigma}{d \cos\theta}$)?

I'm unfamiliar with the literature, so I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!